# Android- How to upload image to Firebase under specific users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app, and so far it's able to upload images, and register users.
However, these two functionalities run independent of each other. Ergo, I need to make it so that the images are saved under the user that uploads it. I am a novice Android programmer and just started learning about Firebase and could use the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Registration process,

```
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, email)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    android.util.Log.e("Firebase", "performFirebaseRegistration:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        AlertUtils.showAlert(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.sign_up), task.getException().getMessage());
                    } else {
                      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = task.getResult().getUser(); // here you will get userDetails 
                    }
                }
            });
```

From firebaseUser you can get user id by firebaseUser.getUid().

Once you upload the message,sent to realtime firebase b the user id as below,

```
  DatabaseReference database =    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    database.child(ARG_USERS)  
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
            .child("image")
            .setValue(<you image download url>);
```

Comment: How do I reference firebaseUser if the image upload is on another activity?

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() this will give you current user instance for entire project

Comment: Yes but  .child(firebaseUser.getUid()) says it cannot resolve firebaseUser

Comment: To clarify, how do I reference firebaseUser variable from the image upload activity? @Priya